# Mocking or Stubbing mtime for File::Stat

Tags: file, rspec, mocking, net-http, if-modified-since

My object `GET`s a file over HTTP.

It does so, using the `If-Modified-Since` header. If the files has not been modified since the time in the header a Not Modified response will be returned and the file should not be fetched&written. Like so:

```
class YouTube
  #...
  def parse
    uri = URI("http://i.ytimg.com/vi/#{@id}/0.jpg")
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    if File.exists? thumbname
      stat = File.stat thumbname
      req['If-Modified-Since'] = stat.mtime.rfc2822
    end

    res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
      http.request(req)
    }

    File.open(thumbname, 'wb') do |f|
      f.write res.body
    end if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
  end
  #...
end
```

I want to test both cases (in both cases, a file on disk exists). To do so, I'd need to stub either something in `Net::HTTP`, or I need to stub the File.stat to return an `mtime` for which I a sure the online resource will return a new or Not-modified-since.

Should I stub (or even mock) `Net::HTTP`? And if so, what?

Or should I stub `mtime` to return a date far in the past or far in the future to enforce or suppress the Not-modified Header?

---

Edit: Diving deeper into the matter, I learned that the *i.ytimg.com*-domain does not support these headers. So i'll need to solve this by inspecing JSON from the YouTube API. However, the problem "What and how to mock when testing if-modified-since-headers" still stands.

Here is how I conclude the domain does not support this:

```
$curl -I --header 'If-Modified-Since: Sun, 24 Mar 2013 17:33:29 +0100' -L http://i.ytimg.com/vi/D80QdsFWdcQ/0.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Sun, 24 Mar 2013 16:31:10 GMT
Expires: Sun, 24 Mar 2013 22:31:10 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: sffe
Content-Length: 13343
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: public, max-age=21600
Age: 822
```

There is no "Last-Modified" there. Illustrated with another call, to exaple.com, which does support the if-modified-since headers.

```
$curl -I --header 'If-Modified-Since: Sun, 24 Mar 2013 17:33:29 +0100' -L example.com
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/
Server: BigIP
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0

HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Date: Sun, 24 Mar 2013 16:47:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Location: http://www.iana.org/domains/example
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

HTTP/1.1 304 NOT MODIFIED
Date: Sun, 24 Mar 2013 16:47:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Connection: close
```